# How can I find roots of a function using Sperner's Lemma?

Tags: algorithms, roots

The Wikipedia page on Sperner's Lemma gives on of its applications as follows:
[Sperner's lemma applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzo8y.png)

i.e. Sperner colorings have been used for effective computation of fixed points. A Sperner coloring can be constructed such that fully labeled simplices correspond to fixed points of a given function. By making a triangulation smaller and smaller, one can show that the limit of the fully labeled simplices is exactly the fixed point. Hence, the technique provides a way to approximate fixed points.

For this reason, Sperner's lemma can also be used in root-finding algorithms and fair division algorithms; see Simmons–Su protocols.

But, there is no method given to find roots. Please help me.

Comment: How about Newton's method?

Comment: Newton's method is good and quite convenient but I was looking for applications of Sperner's lemma for a project I have.

Comment: Newton’s method is a fixed point method